# Option.SupplyData in spa Prerendering not working in production?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I folow tutorial .net core angular ssr in this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio),

in this part, I try passing some text and its working perfectly in development mode but not in production mode.

```
//on .net core

options.SupplyData = (context, data) =>
{
    // Creates a new value that's passed to TypeScript code
    data["meta"] = "title";
};
```

---

```
//angular, on main.server.ts


{ provide: 'MetaTitle', useValue: params.data.meta},
```

and i injecting to component to get data

```
constructor(
     @Optional() @Inject("MetaTitle") private mtitle: any,
) {
}
```

i get value in development not in production code. how to resolve this, help

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include much information about the project, so I'm going to make some assumptions to assist you. Go check these things out in your project

1. assuming that you are using the Angular CLI, make sure that the /dist folder is producing an acceptable index.html
2. make sure the /src/environment.prod.ts looks correct (similar in most cases) to the /src/environment/environment.ts file. This config file controls differences in production vs development builds on the Angular side.

Comment: hi, im using angular cli, the result of building angular is working fine and web is working. the only problem is passing value between the two.(.net core and angular) using supply data option.

Comment: the only different environtment is UseAngularCliServer in development and not in production

Comment: what happens when you overwrite that file with the contents of environment.ts and try ng build --prod?